# Does not contain the value in the Input in IE8 \ IE9

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

There is input:

```
<input type="submit" id="SomeId" value="Search" class="mc-button mc-button-orange" />
```

styles:

```
.mc-button-orange {
border: solid #A26F19;
border-image: initial;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F2BD65, #CB891E);
}

.mc-button {
min-width: 10px;
line-height: 24px;
height: 24px;
padding: 0 28px;
padding-top: 2px;
text-align: center;
-moz-transition: all 0.218s ease 0s;
-moz-user-select: none;
background: #1B7BCB;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#6AC3EB), to(#1B7BCB));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6AC3EB, #1B7BCB);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6AC3EB, #1B7BCB);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#6AC3EB, #1B7BCB);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#6AC3EB, #1B7BCB);
background: linear-gradient(#6AC3EB, #1B7BCB);
color: white;
display: table;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-outline-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0px solid #0076A3;
border-bottom: 1px solid #1564A5;
overflow: visible;
cursor: pointer;
clear: none;
float: left;
}
```

Rounded corners are made by libraries PIE.

In IE8 \ IE9 does not appear within the input word "Search".

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Looking ahead, disable PIE for these classes and the tag does not help.

Translated by GoogleTranslate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `display: table;` will solve this problem